# How can I disable dragging all website in ipad2?

Tags: ipad-2

I make a website display in ipad2, and everytime I put one finger, hold and drag up or down, all the website also move up and down. Could you please tell me how to disable it, guys?

I have tested with the google.com too, hold the finger, move up and down on the ipad2 face, and all website move up and down, seem every website are the same result.

Any anwser are welcome, I really appreciate

Comment: I have found the solution is we need to capture the events happen on ipad, like ontouchmove, ontouchstart.... and use this event.preventDefault(). to prevent the thing i mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below meta tag to your head

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable = no" />
```

Comment: this is just for zoom only, if we set user-scalable = no, it mean the website cannot zoom.